# when using FileStream to open a file, I am wondering whether or not the file will be locked?

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering in which case .Net will lock the file when one use FileStream or similar mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "lock the file", but when stream initialized using:

- [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) = `None` - Declines sharing of the current file. Any request to open the file (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.

Check out MSDN [FileShare Enumeration page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) which contains a detailed description for each share mode.

Comment: Only the FileShare argument matters.

Comment: @Hans Passant : hm interesting, thanks for the point, do not know this before. So multiple streams can write into the same file in the same time... could be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that yourself:

```
var file = new FileStream("C:\\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

if you use FileAccess.Read it will stay unlocked, with Write or ReadWrite it will be locked.

Comment: Strictly speaking it won't be "unlocked" when using this overload, it will default to `FileShare.Read`, i.e. subsequent requests to open the file for writing or to delete the file will fail.  This is probably appropriate in most situations, but the nearest to "unlocked" would require an overload that takes a `FileShare` parameter set to `FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete`.